# How to get driving distance between two point?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

I want to create the application that can calculate the driving distance between point A to point B. I know that the `CLLocation` has `distanceFromLocation:` to calculate the distance between 2 points but it calculate only the straight line from point A to B. Does it has the way to calculate the driving distance between 2 points? How? Any sample?

Thanks

Comment: Can't discuss it because of NDA, but look at iOS7 MapKit changes.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3:

```
func routingDistance(userNotation: CLLocation, destinationLocation: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (CLLocationDistance) -> Void) {
    let request:MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

    // source and destination are the relevant MKMapItems
    let sourceS = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userNotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userNotation.coordinate.longitude)
    let destinationD = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: destinationLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: destinationLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let sourcePM = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceS)
    let destinationPM = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationD)
    request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePM)
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPM)

    // Specify the transportation type
    request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile;

    // If you're open to getting more than one route,
    // requestsAlternateRoutes = true; else requestsAlternateRoutes = false;
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

    directions.calculate { (response, error) in
        if let response = response, let route = response.routes.first {
            completion(route.distance)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any functionality in iOS, `distanceFromLocation` will give the air distance between two co-ordinates.

but yes you can calculate road distance using [google APIS](https://developers.google.com/maps/).

Comment: unfortunately you have to pay for this api (if you have decent usage)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5+:**
If you are looking for driving distance, you can always use MKDirections.
Here is the code for finding driving distance (You can also find walking, and transit distance by changing transport type).

```
let sourceP = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( sourceLat, sourceLong)
let destP = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( desLat, desLong)
let source = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceP)
let destination = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destP)
        
let request = MKDirections.Request()
request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: source)
request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destination)

// Specify the transportation type
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile;

// If you want only the shortest route, set this to a false
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

 // Now we have the routes, we can calculate the distance using
 directions.calculate { (response, error) in
    if let response = response, let route = response.routes.first {
                print(route.distance) //This will return distance in meters
    }
 }
```

If you are only looking for air distance/bird's eye distance/coordinate distance, you can use this code:

```
let sourceP = CLLocation(latitude: sourceLat, longitude: sourceLong)
let desP = CLLocation(latitude: desLat, longitude: desLong))

let distanceInMeter = sourceP.distance(from: desP)
```